# How to avoid the Black box appeared when hidden the navigationbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, uinavigationbar

I have a app with main page is a hidden navigationbar ,and when I back from child page with navigationbar to this main page ,because I set the navigation hidden in the main page method: - (void)viewWillAppear, I　found that a black box will appear with animation, how to avoid it? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 14):

Ok , I find the answer:

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 7):

This fixes the problem without hacking the colour, which could lead to navigation controllers being the wrong colour.

Just set it to be animated in viewWillAppear :)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

and if you go back to page with nav controller set Animation to NO

```
- (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: animated: YES. Who would have guessed?

Comment: me apparently :-p

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help someone if its happening in a tabbar controller app while switching between tabs

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
            if self.navigationController?.visibleViewController != self {
                self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm on Xamarin.iOS (translated to C# obviously)

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift3.0**

In First ViewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(true)
     self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
```

In Second ViewController

```
func backButtonPressed() {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call layoutSubviews() after your call to hide or show the navigation bar:

```
[self.navigationController.view layoutSubviews];
```